# Applications of Set Covering

Tags: graphs, set-cover

I am interested in the applications for set covering. On Wikipedia and [this thread](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/74407/what-are-the-real-world-applications-of-set-cover-problem), I read that it is used in antivirus programs, random testing in software, and personnel scheduling. Does anyone know where to find or access set covering benchmarks that represent those problems (or any other problem for that matter)? Most set covering benchmarks available online are randomly generated and do not have a strong link with a "real" problem.

Comment: Here is an example: http://people.brunel.ac.uk/~mastjjb/jeb/orlib/scpinfo.html

Comment: A few other are listed here: http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2010/11/2814.pdf

Comment: Thank for you for the links. If I understood correctly, the railway benchmarks are based on a "real" problem but the other benchmarks are randomly generated set covering problems. It would be great if one could have more realistic instances.

Comment: The second link has other "real world" problems, such as crew scheduling problems from American Airlines.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that part. Thank you for the reference!